# Ways of monitoring event queue?

Tags: wxpython, wxwidgets

I'm concerned about my application piling up events and I was wondering if there is a way of monitoring the number of events currently in the event queue. Something like `pendingEvents = wx.GetEvents()`, or maybe getting events of a certain type that are currently pending. i.e. `pendingFooEvents = wx.GetEvents('EVT_FOO')`.

Below is just some dummy code which posts several events when I click on a button, and prints an output so I can monitor. There is a sleep statement so that they don't finish immediately. I'm wondering if there is a way my program can recognize that those events have been posted, but they have not finished.

```
import wx
import wx.lib.newevent
import threading
import time

class Frame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title=title, pos=(150, 150), size=(350, 200))

        panel = wx.Panel(self)
        box = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        m_text = wx.StaticText(panel, -1, "Hello World!")
        m_text.SetFont(wx.Font(14, wx.SWISS, wx.NORMAL, wx.BOLD))
        m_text.SetSize(m_text.GetBestSize())
        box.Add(m_text, 0, wx.ALL, 10)

        m_foo = wx.Button(panel, -1, "Foo")
        m_foo.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnPostEvent)
        box.Add(m_foo, 0, wx.ALL, 10)

        panel.SetSizer(box)
        panel.Layout()

        self.fooEvent, EVT_FOO = wx.lib.newevent.NewEvent()
        self.Bind(EVT_FOO, self.MyEvent)

    def OnPostEvent(self, event):
        thread0 = threading.Thread(target=self.PostThings, args=(0,))
        thread1 = threading.Thread(target=self.PostThings, args=(1,))
        thread2 = threading.Thread(target=self.PostThings, args=(2,))
        thread0.start()
        thread1.start()
        thread2.start()

    def PostThings(self, arg):
        wx.PostEvent(self, self.fooEvent(foo=arg))

    def MyEvent(self, event):
        time.sleep(1)
        print(event.foo)


app = wx.App()   # Error messages go to popup window
top = Frame("<<project>>")
top.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: I don't think anything like this exist in wxWidgets. Do you have any problems and/or issues with the event handling? Why do you concerned?

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was thinking, but I figured I'd ask. I have a large system level Gui built on wxPython, and over time the Gui slows down and will eventually freeze (couple hours). Tracking down the issue has been very slow going, and I figured if I could monitor the event queue then maybe I could get something from that, or handle things more intelligently such as not adding certain events if they are already on the queue.

Comment: are you closely following the different demo samples found in wxPython? Usually the symptoms you describe are with the memory or resource leakage, not events

Comment: It will be better to profile and find th expensive part of your logic. Right now I can think of wxYieldIfNeeded() and transferring that parts to secondary thread(s). You need to translate my sentences into Python though